# How do we calculate DHKey using A's public key and B's private key?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

I have 2 set of public/private keys. I would like to know how I can calculate DHKey.

e.g:

```
P-192
Private A:   07915f86918ddc27005df1d6cf0c142b625ed2eff4a518ff
Private B:   1e636ca790b50f68f15d8dbe86244e309211d635de00e16d
Public A(x): 15207009984421a6586f9fc3fe7e4329d2809ea51125f8ed
Public A(y): b09d42b81bc5bd009f79e4b59dbbaa857fca856fb9f7ea25
DHKey:       fb3ba2012c7e62466e486e229290175b4afebc13fdccee46
```

These data have been extracted from the Bluetooth v4.2 Core Specification.

Comment: Are you looking for a theoretical explanation or implementations?

Comment: I am looking for an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the shared secret `DHKey` is the first coordinate of the $b$th multiple of the point $A$, denoted $[b]A$.
Here, $b$ represents B's private key `Private B` and $A$ is A's public key `Public A`.

Using the computer algebra package [sage](http://sagemath.org/), this can be computed as follows. First, we set up the NIST curve P-192 (the constants can be found online):

```
sage: p = 6277101735386680763835789423207666416083908700390324961279
sage: b = 0x64210519e59c80e70fa7e9ab72243049feb8deecc146b9b1
sage: E = EllipticCurve(Zmod(p), [0, 0, 0, -3, b])
```

Then, we plug in the given values and compute $Q:=[b]A$:

```
sage: b = 0x1e636ca790b50f68f15d8dbe86244e309211d635de00e16d
sage: Ax = 0x15207009984421a6586f9fc3fe7e4329d2809ea51125f8ed
sage: Ay = 0xb09d42b81bc5bd009f79e4b59dbbaa857fca856fb9f7ea25
sage: Q = b * E(Ax, Ay)
```

...yielding the desired value:

```
sage: hex(Integer(Q[0]))
'fb3ba2012c7e62466e486e229290175b4afebc13fdccee46'
```

If you want to perform this computation in a different environment (other programming languages, etc.), I am sure you will find plenty of implementations for point multiplication on P-192 using your favourite internet search engine.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. It would have been even better if you provided command line tools, but that's not the point. Thank you.